# getting all tags for a product in an arbitrary store view

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm trying to search for all the tags assigned to a particular product, and using this code to do so:

```
    $model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
    $prod_collection = $model->getResourceCollection()
        ->addPopularity()
        ->addStatusFilter($model->getApprovedStatus())
        ->addProductFilter((int) $productId)
        ->setFlag('relation', true)
        ->addStoreFilter((int) $store['id'])
        ->setActiveFilter()
        ->load();
```

`$store['id']` is **1**, and `$productId` is **13065** (a product that I assigned a couple of tags directly using the backend).

The content of tag_relations if searching for `product_id = 13065` is this:
[image: tag_relations]

As you can see the product has a couple tags assigned on store = 1, and another one assigned on store = 9.

But the above search returns an empty set. I checked the produced SQL and I see that what I'm getting is:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `summary_store`.* FROM `tag` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `tag_relation` AS `relation` ON main_table.tag_id = relation.tag_id
 LEFT JOIN `tag_summary` AS `summary_store` ON main_table.tag_id = summary_store.tag_id 

 WHERE (main_table.status = 1)
    AND (`relation`.`product_id` = 13065)
    AND (summary_store.store_id IN (1))
    AND (relation.store_id IN (1))
    AND (relation.active = 1)

 GROUP BY `main_table`.`tag_id`, `main_table`.`tag_id`
```

And I see that it fails because the contents of tag_summary are:
[image: tag_summary]

where apparently every summary line is stored with store_id = 0, instead of saving one line per store.

How can I change my search so it doesn't join against `tag_summary`, and only against `tag_relations`? Does the content of my `tag_summary` look alright, or should I have a summary line per each store view?

**Update**:

It would seem that the problem is that the corresponding summary lines aren't being generated. I created my tags using the admin, in Catalog->Manage Tags, and assigned the tags to arbitrary products, but it only creates the summary lines for Store ID 0... :(

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rewriting my search as:

```
$model         = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
$tagCollection = $model->getResourceCollection()
        ->addPopularity()
        ->addStatusFilter($model->getApprovedStatus())
        ->addProductFilter((int)$productId);


$tagCollection->getSelect()->where('relation.store_id IN (?)', $store['id']);
```

I don't like this solution very much, and I still think something is wrong on how the summary lines are being saved, but can't find any documentation on how to proceed. Leaving this up until a better answer comes along.